# Sweep direction of arc in ring diagram

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create an arc diagram where the arc represents the start and end of a time stamp.

My problem is that when the start variable is larger than the end value (for instance 14:00-5:00), the arc reverses direction and draws itself counter-clockwise. This is the result of a change made in the source code as shown here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/2dc51055b4aa85496ceb12363f492ad0ad697780

I'm a beginner/intermediate with d3.js and it would be awesome if someone could help show me how to disable this function so that my arcs will always be drawn clockwise from start to finish.

Thanks!
-Sam

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by making two arcs. One from starting to 2Pi and the second from zero to the ending point.

Before this I added the check if starting angle > ending angle.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same issue today, But to the solution is based on @ABJ approaches.

I have compared starting angle > ending angle.

Here is the solution

```js
svg.attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

    svg.select('g')
      .selectAll('.arc')
      .data(pieData)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'arc')
      .each(function(d) {
        const arcStart = timeScale(d.data.start.getTime() % totalTime);
        const arcEnd = timeScale(d.data.end.getTime() % totalTime);
    
        const startAngle = Math.min(arcStart, arcEnd);
        const endAngle = Math.max(arcStart, arcEnd);
    
        const isClockwise = arcEnd >= arcStart;

        const arcGenerator = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 30)
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .cornerRadius(8) // Set the corner radius to 8px (adjust as needed);
    
        let arcPath; // Create a path for the arc
    
        if (isClockwise) {
          arcPath = arcGenerator({
            startAngle,
            endAngle,
          }) + 'L' + arcGenerator({
            startAngle: endAngle,
            endAngle: startAngle,
          }) + 'Z';
        } else {
          arcPath = arcGenerator({
            startAngle: endAngle,
            endAngle: startAngle + Math.PI * 2,
          }) + 'L' + arcGenerator({
            startAngle: startAngle + Math.PI * 2,
            endAngle: endAngle + Math.PI * 2,
          }) + 'Z';
        }
    
        d3.select(this).append('path')
          .attr('d', arcPath)
          .attr('fill', '#845ec2')
          .attr('stroke', '#845ec2')
          .attr('stroke-width', 0.1);
      });
```